# Create a scheduled task to trigger on a log event with a specific event ID

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a manual routine (involving the Scheduled Task GUI) for creating a scheduled task that triggers on a [given set of events from the event log](https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend#triggers-tab). I would like to automate that process *using Powershell* (alternatively using some other scripting tool) and I have found a [small how-to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/) with some examples, as well as the documentation for [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtasktrigger?view=win10-ps).

Unfortunately, the docs do not show any view of creating a task for some specific event id. It only lists one specific non-time related trigger - `-AtLogOn`.

How would I register such a task? Could for instance `Get-Eventlog` be used? [New-ScheduledTask](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask) mentions "trigger objects", but not how to create them and the docs to [Triggers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc748841(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) are no longer updated and contains no PowerShell relevant info. The docs for `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` seems like exactly what I want:

> The New-ScheduledTaskTrigger cmdlet creates and returns a new scheduled task trigger object.

But as I mentioned above, the docs doesn't mention anything about event ids.

Comment: Similar question here https://superuser.com/questions/1481946/how-to-launch-a-bat-file-the-second-internet-disconects-windows-10/1481970#1481970 but with a different event ID.

Comment: @spikey_richie That's exactly what I _don't want_ :-) As I wrote, I want to do this using Powershell. My current routine involves manually creating the trigger using the gui. The `powershell` tag is also a hint :-)

Comment: @spikey_richie Found a solution. It doesn't show how to programmatically build the trigger, but it's a workaround that achieves the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50353591/200987), albeit not strictly using PowerShell, but rather a combination of XML and the `schtask` command. The info was retrieved from this Microsoft blog: [Trigger a PowerShell Script from a Windows Event](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/).

### For the users of the script

The intended users of the script can now just run this in a terminal:

```
schtasks /create /TN "My Super Duper Tasks\The task id 101" /XML my-task.xml
```

This assumes the script has been installed in a designated area, like `C:\my-script.bat`, otherwise Windows won't have anything to run.

### For the author of script

The following steps is of course only for the *author* of the script, not its intended users!

1. Manually create a trigger like you normally would ([example](https://github.com/fatso83/vmware-auto-suspend/tree/027faf6c03fd3bd7b6c6d3dd028bbbb8315ef17b#installing)).
2. Right click the trigger and export it to an XML file.
3. Right click the trigger and *delete it* (it will be recreated from the XML later on).
4. Remove the sections `Principals` and `RegistrationInfo` in the XML file, as they contain hard coded information about user ids that is not present on other computers. It will be recreated using `schtasks`.
5. Run the `schtask` command given above (for the users)