# How to use the same DNS servers regardless of the connected WiFi network in Windows?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, dns

I want to use the same DNS servers with any WiFi network I connect to in Windows. Currently the DNS server addresses I set (in the WiFi adapter properties - TCP/IPv4) are tied to the particular SSID I'm connected to, i.e. when I change to a different WiFi network, the DNS server addresses I set for the previous WiFi network no longer apply.

Is there a way to set it to use the same DNS server addresses with every WiFi network I connect to?

Answer (score 0):

Note first that some public WiFi at coffee shops and libraries that have
a "Captive Portal" may require using the DNS supplied via DHCP,
so will not work with a fixed public DNS.

That said, there are two parts to my solution:

1. A command that will set the DNS server for the network interface
2. If you want this to run automatically, schedule a script to run
   when the network is connected.

The command to use is
[netsh](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts),
which requires elevation.

The specific syntax is:

```
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Network-adapter" static "DNS server"
```

where "Network-adapter" is the name of your network adapter and
"DNS server" is the IP address of the DNS server that you want to use.

For example:

```
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Wi-Fi" static 1.1.1.1
```

To list all your adapter names, use the command:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

If you prefer using PowerShell to set the DNS server, use:

```
Get-NetAdapter -Name "Network_Adapter_Name" | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```

For the second part, for scheduling a script to run when a certain network
is connected, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1482061/8672).

Useful references:

- [Windows Task Scheduler: Trigger an Event When Internet Connects/Disconnects](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-run-script-on-internet-connect-network-connection-drop/)
- [Configure IP Address and DNS from Command Line](https://tweaks.com/windows/40339/configure-ip-address-and-dns-from-command-line/)
- [How To Change IP Address Using Command Prompt](https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/change-ip-address-and-dns-servers-using-the-command-prompt/)